# What's the orbital inclination range Crew Dragons can reach if the Falcon 9 first stage is about to be recovered?

Tags: orbital-elements, dragon-v2, international-politics, inclination, droneship

[Inspiration4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inspiration4) was one of the [very few orbital spaceflights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draft:List_of_orbital_solo_flights_of_manned_spacecraft_in_the_21st_century) in this century that didn't go to a space station. Yet, it reached an orbital inclination of 51.6°, same as the ISS. I believe this is due to the route of the drone ship the first stage of the Falcon 9 lands on: having an inclination of e.g. 29° would probably result in the drone ship entering waters of the Bahamas. Taking the political sea boundaries into account, what is actually the range of inclinations the Crew Dragon can reach, so that the drone ship can retrieve the first stage in either U.S. or international waters?

Comment: I assume you mean *manned* orbital spaceflights.  Lots of unmanned missions don't go to space stations.

Comment: I really don't think there's any evidence the drone ship is a trajectory-limiter. Starlink launches routinely recover on the drone ships and launch to a large range of inclinations.

Comment: [Yesterday's Starlink launch](https://youtu.be/aOLE7ATfQko?t=2185) is an example of a launch that didn't go to 51.6 degrees, and in fact launched to the southeast, but not quite so far SE as The Bahamas. [Relevant Spaceflightnow link](https://spaceflightnow.com/2024/02/29/live-coverage-spacex-squeezes-in-falcon-9-launch-of-starlink-satellites-from-the-cape-following-crew-8-astronaut-delay/)

Comment: I think you're correct that all Crew Dragon flights, including Jared Isaacman's Polaris/Inspiration flights and the upcoming Vast Haven flights, go to the same inclination. But it isn't about first stage recovery; I agree with [this thread's speculation](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=58838.0) that it's about using the same recovery/contingency-abort zones for Crew Dragon for each launch.  I think there's still a way to answer the question you've asked here (do drone ship recoveries limit orbit inclinations) but also another Q and A about Crew Dragon's inclination limits

Comment: In the part of the question "if the Falcon 9 first stage is *about* to be recovered" the word "about" doesn't seem to be adding anything. Is it needed?